# Can I execute a stored procedure every month automatically without creating a job?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do not have access to SQL Server Agent and would like to execute a stored procedure monthly from SQL Server Management Studio 14. I am trying to insert the syntax for a stored procedure that will ensure it will be executed anytime I log into the client.

How would I do this?

Comment: That is called a [logon trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15). See the link for how to create this.

Comment: You can also schedule sqlcmd scripts through windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: your discription is pretty unclear. It sounds like "i want to schedule sth without to schedule it"

Comment: "every month automatically" and "anytime I log into the client" are not really consistent, are they? If you want to do something on a **schedule**, then the agent is the typical method. Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to accomplish and why you want to rule out certain functionality? Given the contradiction and lack of detail, this smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ideally I would like table to be updated every month and I would like to run something on a schedule but don't have access to SQL server Agent. However, the frequency of the table being updated does not in fact matter so if I was able to update the table upon logging in that would solve the same problem in a much less eloquent way

Comment: IMHO operational concerns should have an operational solution: Use `crontab` (*nix) or `at` (windows) for scheduled executions.